# Filter collection by multi-reference field

Tags: velo

I'm trying to filter a collection by a multireference field before the function does its job.

I used this wix example but I don't want it to filter the whole collection https://www.wix.com/corvid/example/filter-with-multiple-options

I'm new at this and probably doing it wrong this is what i managed to figure out

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

const collectionName = 'Blog/Posts'
//const collectionName = wixData.query('Blog/Posts').contains("categories", ["O -Fitness"]);

const fieldToFilterByInCollection = 'hashtags';


$w.onReady(function () {

    setRepeatedItemsInRepeater()
    loadDataToRepeater()

    $w('#tags').onChange((event) => {
        const selectedTags = $w('#tags').value
        loadDataToRepeater(selectedTags)
    })
});

function loadDataToRepeater(selectedCategories = []) {

    let dataQuery = wixData.query(collectionName)//.contains("categories", ["O -Fitness"]);


    if (selectedCategories.length > 0) {
        dataQuery = dataQuery.hasAll(fieldToFilterByInCollection, selectedCategories)
    }

    dataQuery
        .find()
        .then(results => {
            const itemsReadyForRepeater = results.items
            $w('#Stories').data = itemsReadyForRepeater;

            const isRepeaterEmpty = itemsReadyForRepeater.length === 0

            if (isRepeaterEmpty) {
                $w('#noResultsFound').show()
            } else {
                $w('#noResultsFound').hide()
            }
        })
}

function setRepeatedItemsInRepeater() {
    $w('#Stories').onItemReady(($item, itemData) => {

        $item('#image').src = itemData.coverImage;
        $item('#title').text = itemData.title;
        if ($item("#title").text.length > 40){
        $item("#title").text =$item("#title").text.slice(0, 40) + '...' ;}
        $item('#excerpt').text = itemData.excerpt;
        if ($item('#excerpt').text.length > 100){
        $item('#excerpt').text =$item('#excerpt').text.slice(0, 100) + '...' ;}     



    })
}
```

its this commented bit I'm trying to add

```
const collectionName = wixData.query('Blog/Posts').contains("categories", ["O -Fitness"]);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate which part of this is not working? Now since you have implemented your solution what exactly is not working?

Comment: @vaibhavmande sorry instead of reading this collection like this    ` const collectionName = 'Blog/Posts'`    I want to to prefilter the blog/posts field called categories with the key as O -Fitness like this but it isnt working      `const collectionName = wixData.query('Blog/Posts').contains("categories", ["O -Fitness"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You used 'hasAll' to filter multi-refernce field. 'hasSome' working on multi-refernce but 'hasAll' isnt working on this field type.

you can use:

```
selectedCategories.map(category => {
   dataQuery = dataQuery.hasSome(fieldToFilterByInCollection, category)
})
```

which is the same as hasAll - hasSome(x) & hasSome(Y) = hasAll(x,y) - but beacuse 'hasSome' is working on multirefernce it will work:)